# how to remotely control raspberry pi gpio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm doing a face recognition project that uses opencv and python to recognize a person's face on a pc. Now, my goal is to use a raspberry pi to access one of my gpio ports, and when One face was detected in my pc then to turn on a led. My problem is how can I connect my pc to a raspberry pi and use the code that runs on my pc to run the raspberry pi gpio?

Comment: How are your pc and your computer connected? Over local network? Over the internet? Which programming languages are you comfortable with?

Comment: While this question is on-topic here, it's probably a better match for 
 the [raspberrypi.se] site. You can click the 'flag' link below your post, select 'other', and ask a moderator to migrate it there.

Comment: And perhaps a ESP Module with espeasy which sets a pin in a MQTT message would better fit your need

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [GPIO Zero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html) due to its excellent remote GPIO support.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote "**mqtt-gpio**" which connects MQTT topics to Raspberry Pi GPIO pins. It is a general purpose connector which supports input and output pins; groups of pins; and complex inching. Configurable with YAML, and will be very easy to switch a LED on and off based on a MQTT topic.

There are prebuilt container images on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/sourcesimian/mqtt-gpio). The docs/source are on GitHub: [README.md](https://github.com/sourcesimian/mqtt-gpio/blob/main/README.md).

I run it in [K3s](https://k3s.io/) (but will work on Docker too) on [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/). The service is built on [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/).  At present I use it to:

- drive relays for my irrigation solenoids and ball valve manipulators,
- detect open/closed state of doors/windows,
- and remotely press various buttons.

Setting up a MQTT broker and publishing to a MQTT is relatively easy too. You can install [Eclipse Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/), or just use [EMQ X](https://www.emqx.io/) or other free cloud MQTT providers. Publishing to a MQTT topic from Python is also simple using the `paho.mqtt` library.